# Hadamard's Lemma in multidimensional real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

This is Hadamard's Lemma:

Let $U \subset \Bbb R^n$ be an open set, let $a \in U$ and $f: U \to \Bbb R^p$. Then the following assertions are equivalent.

1. The mapping $f$ is differentiable at $a$.
2. There exists an operator-valued mapping $\phi = \phi_a: U \to \operatorname{Lin}(\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^p)$ continuous at $a$, such that $$f(x) = f(a) + \phi_a(x)(x-a).$$ If one of these conditions is satisfied we have $\phi_a(a) = Df(a)$.

I'm struggling with implication $2 \Longrightarrow 1$. The book claims it is straightforward using a lemma that says that for an operator $A$ we have $\| A h \| \leq \| A \| \| h \|$, it's the Euclidean norm.

**I think I've solved it as follows, and I would like to know if it's correct:**

If $f$ has the given representation then we have $$f(a+h) = f(a) + \phi_a(a+h) h$$ for all vectors $h=x-a$. Since $\phi_a(a+h) \in \operatorname{Lin}(\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^p)$ then $\phi_a(a+h) = \phi_a(a) + \phi_a(h)$ and we have $$f(a+h) = f(a) + \phi_a(a)h + \phi_a(h)h.$$ We need to show now that $\epsilon_a(h) = \phi_a(h)h$ satisfies $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\| \epsilon_a (h)\|}{\| h\|} = 0.$$ (This is an equivalent definition of differentiability presented in the book.) We have $$0 \leq \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\| \epsilon_a (h)\|}{\| h\|} \leq \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\| \phi_a(h) \| \|h \|}{\| h \|} = \lim_{h \to 0} \| \phi_a(h) \|,$$ and since $\phi_a(h) \operatorname{Lin}(\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^p)$ this evaluates to zero, proving $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: No. That $\phi_a(a+h)\in \operatorname{Lin}(\mathbb{R}^n,m\mathbb{R}^p)$ does not mean $\phi_a(a+h) = \phi_a(a) + \phi_a(h)$. It means $\phi_a(a+h)(u+v) = \phi_a(a+h)(u) + \phi_a(a+h)(v)$.

Comment: You're right. But can you explain the straightforward? I've been at this for quite a while (a few hours).

Comment: But, you have $$\phi_a(a+h)h = \phi_a(a)h + \left(\phi_a(a+h)-\phi_a(a)\right)h.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer A trick, naturally. So this implies $$f(a+h) = f(a) + \phi_a(a) h + (\phi_a(a+h) - \phi_a(a))h$$ and $$0 \leq \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\| (\phi_a(a+h) - \phi_a(a))h \|}{\| h\|} \leq \lim_{h \to 0} \| \phi_a(a+h) - \phi_a \| = 0$$ because $\phi_a$ is continuous at $a$, proving the result, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the representation of 2, we have

$$f(x) - f(a) - \phi_a(a)(x-a) = \left(\phi_a(x) - \phi_a(a)\right)(x-a).$$

Thus

$$\lVert f(x) - f(a) - \phi_a(a)(x-a)\rvert \leqslant \lVert \phi_a(x) - \phi_a(a)\rVert\cdot \lVert x-a\rVert.$$

Now the continuity of $\phi_a$ in $a$ says that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ with

$$\lVert x-a\rVert < \delta \implies \lVert \phi_a(x) - \phi_a(a)\rVert < \varepsilon.$$

Comment: Wow, it was really straightforward. I appreciate it! Is the other way I have presented in my comment valid as well?

Comment: Yes, it is the same thing in green. I say $\forall\varepsilon \exists\delta$, you say $\lim_{h\to 0} = 0$. Colour vs. color.